# Very weird result with geocoder has_many and belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I am using Geocoder Gem, it is showing wired behavior.

I have Location model

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :events
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode
def full_address
    "#{postal_code}, #{city}, #{street}"
  end
end
```

and Event model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end
```

I want to find all events nearby the current user's location.

I tried following steps to find nearby locations..

```
nearby_loc = current_user_location.nearby
```

it is returning all nearby "locations" of current users location

Then I tried

```
nearby_loc.events
```

but it is giving me error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `events' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Location:0x0000000958c088>
```

Please help me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `events` is defined on a location, and 
`nearby` will give you a list of locations, so you will have to iterate over the list.

Simply put:

```
all_related_events  = []
nearby_locations.includes(:events).each do |location|
  all_related_events += location.events
end
```

It also helps if your variable names more correctly reflect what they contain, so use `nearby_locations` instead of `nearby_loc`.

[UPDATE]

To  minimise the number of queries, I added the `.includes(:events)` which will fetch all events in one query.

Comment: its giving error NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
 from (irb):11:in `block in irb_binding'

Comment: again error TypeError: wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module)

Comment: Yep, it should be `includes` obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to start with the query with a model I want to get. Instead of getting "a collection from collection of collections", you can...

Join a `Location` to all events so you can fetch all `Event`s, whose `Location` matches certain conditions. Most of the time a scope is just a bunch of conditions, able to be `merge`d.

Like so:

```
Event.joins(:location)                    # Results in `INNER JOIN`
     .merge(current_user_location.nearby) # Adds in the conditions for locations
```

#### But things are not that simple!

Geocoder does a very complicated `select` under the hood and adds some useful fields like `distance` that depend on the point that was fed into the scope. We can't just lose these, right? The query would stop making any sense.

An option is to do an `INNER JOIN` in a **really weird way**: by specifying the `FROM`-clause to fetch data from **two tables** (more on that later) and specifying the join condition in a `WHERE`-clause. We'll need a bit of Arel for that, so let's fetch tables in advance:

```
locations = Location.arel_table
events    = Event   .arel_table # Yeah, call me an indentation maniac
```

And now here's a catch: instead of `locations` table we'll use results of a subquery formed by `current_user_location.nearby`. How? We'll feed `from` with an array of things we want to use:

```
Event.from([current_user_location.nearby.as('locations'), events])
           # ^ an array, yeah!
```

What we have here is:

```
select events.* from (geocoder subquery) locations, events
```

Now what? A join condition. As I said, since we're making a **weird join**, we'll specify the join condition in `where`. We have to.

```
Event.from([current_user_location.nearby.as('locations'), events])
     .where(location_id: locations[:id])
```

...and that should probably work fine. Done completely by the database at least.

Comment: @Adt huh. So Geocoder's scope has a `select`... let me think for a while

Comment: Oh geez. Looks like we have to alias `locations` to that result set, then join with it, not the actual table. No index will get hit, I imagine... Wow, that feels scary. I have to get myself a minimal setup of Geocoder in Rails, just to be certain.

Comment: @Adt somewhere on an edge of a bug and an implementation detail we shouldn't have hit. `merge` is not used too widely these days, and it's a shame. It allows for some nice moves.

Comment: @Adt nah, `merge` is fragile and easy to break apart. What database are you running on by the way? Type and server version.

Comment: i m running postgre and gem version gem 'pg'         , '0.18.1'

Comment: @Adt not gem, server. Database itself.

Comment: I don't know, can u tell me how i can find that?

Comment: @Adt and a wild guess: try sticking `.select('events.*')` to the end of my query. I doubt that would work, but no harm in trying.

Comment: @Adt database version may be different on your development machine and on Heroku. And it doesn't matter really, the solution I was thinking of won't work. I'm trying out another one.

Comment: @Adt now there is some **serious** Arel trickery. Check out if it works now.

Comment: after running Event.from([current_user_location.nearby.as('locations'), events]) in console it showing wired behavior. query returning 506 rows(origna 30 rows in both tables) and also console is hanging..

Comment: @Adt of course, since you've forgotten a `where` that should filter that down.

Answer (score 2):

In this case

```rb
nearby_loc = current_user_location.nearby
```

returns a list of locations, not a single location.

To iterate through them and find each location's events, you could use

```rb
nearby_events = nearby_loc.map {|loc| loc.events}
```

However, this is not efficient in terms of total queries.

Comment: Your solution is working but it is using lots of database queries..
http://pastebin.com/L4iFn2W1

Comment: Thank you for finding that! I added a possible solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

> NoMethodError: undefined method `events' for
>   ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Location

Your `nearby_loc` is `ActiveRecord::Relation`, so `nearby_loc.events` results an error. You should iterate over `nearby_loc` to get it worked.

```
nearby_loc.each do |n|
n.events
end
```